# Bei einer jährlichen Prämie handelt sich um eine freiwillige Leistung, auf die kein Rechtsanspruch besteht

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Bei einer jährlichen Prämie handelt sich um eine freiwillige Leistung, auf die kein Rechtsanspruch besteht.

I understand the translation .... I just did not understand the construction of the sentence with the preposition "auf": kein Rechtsanspruch besteht auf die Leistung!.... What does "besteht auf" mean in this context?

Comment: See any dictionary, for example https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bestehen (1) or https://www.dwds.de/wb/bestehen (1) or https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bestehen (4).

Comment: Even google translate gives a good translation here: `An annual premium is a voluntary benefit for which there is no legal entitlement.`

Comment: I know its translation .... I just did not understand the construction with the preposition: kein Rechtsanspruch besteht auf die Leistung!.

Comment: The word "auf" is related to "Anspruch", not to "besteht". _Jemand hat Anspruch auf etwas_. _Es besteht ein Anspruch auf Y_. The construction you are referring to could be simplified as "X does not exist" == "X besteht nicht" with X is "(Rechts)Anspruch auf diese freiwillige Leistung"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the verb *bestehen*.

The crucial phrase is here

> Rechtsanspruch auf...

as in

> einen Rechtsanspruch haben auf...
>
> Anspruch auf etwas haben
>
> Anspruch auf etwas vortragen
>
> Anspruch auf etwas erheben
>
> Jeder Mensch hat **Anspruch auf** ordentlichen Wohnraum.
>
> Ich erhebe keinen Anspruch auf Nutzung des Wegerechts auf diesem Grundstück
>
> Ich habe Anspruch auf eine angemessene Berücksichtigung meiner Interessen

Answer (score 4):

bestehen = to exist (here in this context)

a verbatime translation might be:

> eine Leistung, auf die kein Rechtsanspruch besteht.
>   a benefit, on which no entitlement exists.

This means: This is something you might get now, but you have no right to claim the same benefit in the future.